# RStudio - DBI::dbAppendTable() Error: The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) protocol stream is incorrect

Tags: r

I see a very strange behaviour with `DBI::dbAppendTable()` that I can’t understand.
I don’t know if it’s a bug from DBI/odbc or windows.

When I try to insert the following string, I get an error.

```
test <- tibble(
  my_column = "<div>
  <p>
    <strong>En vertu de la loi BIM (loi du 4 février 2010 relative aux méthodes de recueil des données par les services de renseignement et de sécurité), la Sûreté de l’Etat est habilitée à mettre en oeuvre des méthodes spécifiques pour différentes menaces relevant de ses missions légales</strong>
  </p>
</div>"
  )

DBI::dbAppendTable(
  conn = DBI::dbConnect(
      odbc::odbc(),
    Driver = "SQL Server",
      Server = my_Server,
      Database = my_Database,
       Trusted_Connection = "True",
       encoding = "UTF-8"),
  name = DBI::SQL(my_table),
  value = test)
```

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1769: 28000:  
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) protocol stream is incorrect.  
The stream ended unexpectedly.
```

The table (in MS SQL):

> CREATE TABLE [Test].[DBI_test_encoding](
> [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
> [my_column] nvarchar NULL)

I have also noticed that:

- if I add or remove any character from the string, it works ! Even with accentuated characters.
- if I replace any character by a regular one, it works.
- if I replace any regular character by an accentuated one, it doesn’t work.

I think it’s an encoding issue but I don’t know why it happens.
In `DBI::dbConnect()`, if I choose encoding = “CP1252”, it works but the special French accentuated characters like “é” are lost.
I would like to continue to use "UTF-8" encoding.

Any ideas ?

```
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_Belgium.utf8  LC_CTYPE=French_Belgium.utf8    LC_MONETARY=French_Belgium.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=French_Belgium.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] tools     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] DBI_1.1.3              odbc_1.3.5             usethis_2.2.2          testthat_3.1.10       rmarkdown_2.24         
 [6] blastula_0.3.3         rlang_1.1.1            tibble_3.2.1           purrr_1.0.2           dplyr_1.1.2
[11] lubridate_1.9.2
```

Comment: The `"SQL Server"` odbc driver is _ancient_. I suggest you download either v17 or v18 from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server and connect using `Driver="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"` (or 18). There are many differences, some of them cosmetic, most of them quite functional. (I find it mildly amusing/frustrating that Microsoft deploys a driver it no longer recommends as the default/only in all installations of Windows, when the sane alternatives are just as "free".)